# How to access custom cms element config values in Shopware 6?

Tags: shopware

FYI: Products is my cms element name.

As shown in shopware 6 guides, I have created a file

```
DataResolver/ProductsCmsElementResolver.php
```

which has an enrich method which helps to extend data. In there I try to access the configs of my custom cms element with:

```
$config = $slot->getFieldConfig();
$productListType = $config->get('products')->getValue();
```

That, however always returns the default value that was set during the registration of the element:

```
Shopware.Service('cmsService').registerCmsElement({
    name: 'products',
    label: 'das.elements.customProductsElement.label',
    component: 'sw-cms-el-products',
    configComponent: 'sw-cms-el-config-products',
    previewComponent: 'sw-cms-el-preview-products',
    defaultConfig: {
        products: {
            source: 'static',
            value: ''
        }
    }
});
```

I did it exactly as it is shown in the following guides:

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/content/cms/add-cms-element

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/content/cms/add-data-to-cms-elements#create-a-data-resolver

Could anyone share a sample of code where you get the value of config as a variable and not static value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I was doing wrong was that I forgot to write the .value in computed methods:

```
computed: {
        products() {
            return this.element.config.products.value;
        }
    },
```

However I also found such function call in shopware source codes which was not mentioned in the docs:

```
methods: {
        createdComponent() {
            this.initElementConfig('youtube-video');
            this.initElementData('youtube-video'); // this line was not present in docs
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you haven't done any further handling of the product data in your config component, as you do not mention it.
I suggest having a look at the default cms components like for example `shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-cms/elements/product-slider/config/index.js` where you can see how product data is handled :)

Comment: I don't want to handle any data in the component, I just want to get config values of the cms element.

Comment: Oh then I did not understand you correctly, sorry.
It seems like you get the config for this element correctly, this is why I assumed that the products are not saved correctly in the configuration. If you need an example of a core data resolver, have a look at `Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Cms\ProductSliderCmsElementResolver`, maybe this can help you figure it out :)

Comment: just as I said, I am taking the $productListType = $config->get('products')->getValue(); config of my element as it is shown in the ProductSliderCmsElementResolver, however it always returns the default value instead of the current one that is set.